# Error accessing tomcat web server from my mac

Tags: macos, tomcat

support guys in the office can't help and everything has been fine for the last couple months until today. Running OSX 10.6.3 and 1 of only 2 users on mac. Can access a staging server when remoting in to a pc near my desk but not able to access via any of the browsers on my mac (Chrome, Firefox or Safari). An example staging server would be http://mesoderm:8080/...

Error is simply: Oops! Google Chrome could not find mesoderm:8080.

I can connect to the internet and remote in to a nearby pc as mentioned above.

Strange why it would all of a sudden do this and it's incredibly annoying! Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Ryan

Comment: Is anyone else able to access it? i.e. is the mesoderm server up and running on 8080?

Answer (score 0):

Investigate your firewall rules. This is most often the cause of this kind of problems.